# change event and programmatically changing value in focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

From jquery docs: The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. So I have handler to `input` element that listen to `change` event. When I focus this input I have to change it's value, so I have other handler to `focus` event. The problem is that when I lose focus after I programmatically change input's value the `change` event doesn't trigger.

focus handler:

```
focusHandler = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this),
        value = 'FOO';
    elem.val(value );
}
```

how it's bound:

```
$(SF_CONSTANTS.CONTROLS.place).bind('focus', self.placeFocusHandler);
$(SF_CONSTANTS.CONTROLS.place).bind('change', function(event){ self.changeControlHandler('place'); });
```

Why this happens?
fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/TSEt7/)

Comment: please provide us the html too

Comment: And where's the `change` handler and how is it bound?

Comment: Did you test it without the `focus` handler? I mean, are you 100% sure that `focus` handler causes the problem?

Comment: Note that in recent jQuery bind is superseded by on. bind is deprecated.